# How do I commit after merging two repositories?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to merge the old-software repository into the new-software repository. Currently, I am inside a new software git repository and I ran following commands.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/agrawalo/new-software.git
git remote add r1remote https://github.com/agrawalo/old-software.git
git merge r1remote/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

merge is completed. Now I am confused about what will happen if I run git push. Will it commit to the new repo or to the old repo?

Comment: `old-software` repo will be updated with the changes from the merge.

Comment: Have a look at git remote show origin. It will tell you the defaults.